# using regular expression in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic to display a list of contacts from a user. So, when the user enters the number and clicks the add button it should display like (011)123-1234 in the list, and this should be followed for each entry. I tried to set the pattern in the tag but couldn't display the phone number. Please help me.

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="10"  ng-model="phone" pattern="/(?:\(?\+\d{2}\)?\s*)?\d+(?:[ -]*\d+)*$/"> <br>
     <button ng-click="home()">Home</button></n>
     <button ng-click="add()" value="Add">Add</button><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-pattern` instead of `pattern`.

Checkout the [`ngPattern` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) for more details.

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="10"  ng-model="phone" ng-pattern="/(?:\(?\+\d{2}\)?\s*)?\d+(?:[ -]*\d+)*$/">
```

Also, I believe you are looking for a mask directive not a regex.

I suggest [this one](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask) that works well and it is easy to use.